# How to check if array has more elements in twigs for loop?

Tags: symfony, twig

I am currently concatenating array elements in a single variable with , between them. I'm getting record like this

```
abc,def,ghi,
```

I dont want to add an extra comma `,` after last element. My code is:

```
{% for driver in item.vehicles if driver.driver.firstName %}
{% set isDriver = 1 %}
{% set driverList = driverList ~ driver.driver.firstName ~ ',' %}
{% endfor %}
&nbsp;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [TWIG LOOP VARIABLE](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) for your needed like this:

```
{% for driver in item.vehicles if driver.driver.firstName %}
{% set isDriver = 1 %}
{% set driverList = driverList ~ driver.driver.firstName  %}

   {% if loop.last == false %}
   {% set driverList = driverList ~  ',' %}
   {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: tried but it didn't heleped :( its still concatenating , with string.

Comment: it is also giving error “The “loop.last” variable is not defined when looping with a condition.
I tried adding driver in place of loop but by that way it always come inside if condition

Comment: Hi @UmairMalik very strange... i recently used this statement: `{% if not loop.last  %}` try this approach, let me know is this is good for you i will update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than counting the loop you could just create an array of drivers and join them with a `,` like..

```
{% set driverList = [] %}
{% for driver in item.vehicles if driver.driver.firstName %}
    {% set driverList = driverList|merge([driver.driver.firstName]) %}
{% endfor %}
{{ driverList|join(',') }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just test for the last loop index

```
{% for driver in item.vehicles if driver.driver.firstName %}
    {% set isDriver = 1 %}
    {% if loop.index is not sameas(loop.last)  %}
        {% set driverList = driverList ~ driver.driver.firstName ~ ',' %}
    {%else%}
        {% set driverList = driverList ~ driver.driver.firstName  %}
    {%endif%}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks Med for your time, i tried your code it's not coming inside if condition

Answer (score 1):

> The loop.length, loop.revindex, loop.revindex0, and loop.last variables are only available for PHP arrays, or objects that implement the Countable interface. They are also not available when looping with a condition.

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/for.html

You could just do this (if you like to style the name with a link, you should set it to a variable)

```
{% for driver in item.vehicles if driver.driver.firstName %}
  {{ loop.index > 1 ? ', ': ''}}{{ driver.driver.firstName }}
{% endfor %}
```